# ORACLE SQL, DeserializeJSON

Tags: sql, json, deserialization

I have a serialized JSON object as follows:

```
{
"Sender": "Service",
"Type": "SPIGlassAuditedOrder",
"Data": "{\"Header\":{\"Id\":\"ASDFDSA-8687689-ASDFD\",\"EventType\":\"Order\"}"
}
```

In the "Data" path, I want to deserialize that path.  However, I can't get past one, all of the additional "\" and second, the additional set of quotation marks before the Data -> Header path.

I used the following SQL statement that has a JSON_TABLE function:

```
with tmp as (
  select jt1.*
  FROM schema.table t,
    JSON_TABLE(t.payload, '$'
    COLUMNS
      sender PATH '$.Sender',
      type PATH '$.Type',
      data PATH '$.Data') jt1
    where t.queue_config_fk = 37
) select * from tmp;
```

But the Data returns Null:

[image]

What I would prefer to return is an actual deserialized JSON object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_TABLE` creates a virtual table from a JSON. Try to use `JSON_QUERY` to select one or more values.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use JSON_QUERY semantics in JSON_TABLE as follows

```
with tmp as ( 
select jt1.*
FROM schema.table t,
JSON_TABLE(t.payload, '$'
COLUMNS
  sender PATH '$.Sender',
  type PATH '$.Type',
  data VARCHAR2(1000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.Data') jt1
where t.queue_config_fk = 37
```

) select * from tmp;

please note the **VARCHAR2(1000) FORMAT JSON**